# Problem in passing values using props in react.js while using chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-props, react-state

I am using react js and trying to send Props from my app.js to chart.js file. When I send the hardcoded values the values are being send properly and graph is made according to it. But whenever I am passing a dynamic values, values are being passed but not used by chart.

App.js

```
 class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    text: "",
    credit: [{_id:1,financeCredit:"loading"}],
    debit: [{_id:1,financeDebit:"loading"}],
   }

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('/data')
    .then(res=> res.json())
    .then(res2 => {
      console.log(res2)
      this.setState({
        credit: res2
      })
    })

    fetch('/data2')
    .then(res=> res.json())
    .then(res2 => {
      console.log(res2)
      this.setState({
        debit: res2
      })
    })

}

  render(){

var lengthExpense = this.state.credit.length;
console.log(lengthExpense)

var expName = [];

for (var a = 0 ; a <= lengthExpense ; a++){

if (this.state.credit[a]){
    expName.push(this.state.credit[a].expenseName)
}

}

var expAmount = [];

for (var b = 0 ; b <= lengthExpense ; b++){
    if(this.state.credit[b])
    expAmount.push(this.state.credit[b].expenseAmount)
}

console.log(expAmount)
console.log(expName)


    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">   
      <Navbar />
      <Chart  expam = {expAmount} expnam = {expName} />
      <Route exact path = "/" component = {Home} />
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

}

export default App;
```

Although the following console.log() is showing the desired values I want to pass

```
console.log(expAmount)
console.log(expName)
```

I am passing these values like this

```
<Chart  expam = {expAmount} expnam = {expName} />
```

In chart.js although I am getting these values.

Chart.js

```
class Chart extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chartData : {
                labels: this.props.expnam,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Expense',
                    data: this.props.expam,
                    backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
                }]
            }
        }
    }

    render(){

console.log(this.props)

        return(
            <div className = "chart">
                <div>
            <Bar id = "chart1"
            data={this.state.chartData}
            options={{ maintainAspectRatio: false, }}
            />  

            <canvas id = "chart1" height="30vw" width="10vw" ></canvas>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

But couldn't able to pass it to to labels and data. Code is properly running but there is no values so chart is being showed empty

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chartData : {
                labels: this.props.expnam,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Expense',
                    data: this.props.expam,
                    backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
                }]
            }
        }
    }
```

In this chart.js file I can see all the values that are being passed from App.js. But these values are not been used for chart (bar chart).

```
console.log(this.props)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're setting the data in your constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        chartData : {...}
    }
}
```

A constructor is only called *once* when an object is initialized.  (In ReactJS, it is only called after the first render.)

You are calling `setState()`, and the rest appears to be good, that I can tell.  Why don't you move `this.state = {...}` from the constructor to `render()`?  Since `render()` runs whenever the state is changed, your `setState()` calls should work.

It may be inelegant, and there can certainly be improvements, but it will get you started in the right direction.

Comment: This works nicely, I just put this code under the render as you instructed and all things went well. Thanks a lot sir :)